# Typo3 multidomain: Change 1 of the domains to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, typo3, multiple-domains, typo3-4.7

I have a Typo3 installation with 2 domains:
`www.example.de` and `intranet.example.de`

The `www.example.de` website should be built up in wordpress (new) but the `intranet.example.de` should remain as it is (typo3).

Is it possible to change the root path of the domain `www.example.de` to the new wordpress path and the other domain `intranet.example.de` still works without any problems?

Or do I have to consider more and change more settings (in typo3)?

(Version: TYPO3 4.7)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming you have TYPO3 and Wordpress running under different folders on the same server, you can just configure 2 different VHOST files for each domain respectively. No need to change anything in TYPO3 configuration, this is pure server configuration (apache, nginx or whatever you are running).

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Great! Did it answer your question properly? If so mark this question as resolved.